# How do i tell the recycle bin to delete files older than X days?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically deleting old files from recycling bin while keeping the new ones?](https://superuser.com/questions/434626/automatically-deleting-old-files-from-recycling-bin-while-keeping-the-new-ones)

How do i tell the recycle bin to delete files older than X days? I tried writing a program to do it but it seems like a lot of trouble (to bad it isnt just simply checking access time). I found programs which delete ALL files on a schedule but i like to delete only files thats been in there for a few days.

I'm using windows7

Comment: On Windows 7 you can just use **RecycleBinEx** (http://www.fcleaner.com/recyclebinex), a small application that does just this. Please see http://superuser.com/a/615870/85364

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the multitude of answers on ServerFault or StackOverflow. All you have to do is write a batch file or vbs script that looks for files older than X days in the given directory.

Here's [Jeff Atwood's post](https://serverfault.com/questions/49614/delete-files-older-than-x-days) with suggestions for a vbs script. There's also a [batch file approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days) for the same; you might need a few tweaks to get it going for the recycle bin.

Comment: Not helpful. The answers check if the files exist for more then X days. I'd like to delete files when they been in the folder for more than X days. As Patrick S. mentioned if you right click the file and look at the property you can see when it was put in the recycle bin. I just have no idea what winapi to call to get to that

Comment: Don't the answers specifically say that 'files older than X days will be deleted'? The only hitch with those methods is that you have to manually run the scripts to perform deletion. If you're looking for an _automatic_ way to tell the recycle bin to delete such files, then I'm sorry I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

This software is rather old, and I know nothing about it. That being said:

BinManager: http://www.cheztabor.com/BinManager/index.htm

Comment: URL broken July 2017

Comment: Seems like the software is abandoned.